# Differential equation problem with integrating factor that depends on $xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation

$$
(x^2y^2-1)xy'+(x^2y^2+xy)y=0
$$
has an integrating factor that depends only on $xy$, find all the solution $y(x)$

How do I do this? Can I make some substitution or something?

Comment: Is there a substitution you might think of trying? Why not give it a go?

Comment: I tried to write it in terms of t and y but that didn't help.

Comment: Where is $t$ coming from? - The infection is that differentiation is with respect to $x$.

Comment: Ooooh i'm sorry, stupid me. Forgot to say that I made the substitution that $t=xy$ (since the integrating factor depends on that) and then write it in terms of $t$ and $y$. However, that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

This abundancy of $xy$ terms make  thinking about a change $y=\frac z x$, $y'=\frac{x z'-z}{x^2}$. Replacing, this leads to $$\left(z^2-1\right) z'+\frac{z (z+1)}{x}=(z+1)(z-1)z'+\frac{z (z+1)}{x}=0$$ So, there is an obvious solution $z=-1$. Keeping this solution in mind, divide by $(z+1)$ and you are let with $$(z-1)z'+\frac{z }{x}=0$$ which is separable and you will get the second solution in $z$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Nice!  Then I wasn't totally wrong. I was trying to make the substitution $t=xy$ and then write it in terms of $y$ and $t$. But if I take  $y=\frac{t}{x}$ I get exactly what you had. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are ery welcome !